# display, edit then get final changes in JSON data in angular

Tags: json, angular, save, edit, display

I have successfully display my JSON data into an accordion but my problem was that I can't find the way to get the final data after modification :( .
this is the source code link :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-expansion-panel-drag-drop-multi-level-qrdusr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire your inputs to a FormControl/FormGroup so you can keep track of the values https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms